# Removing items from collection

Tags: c#

I have a list of ids, and the items with these ids shall be removed from a Collection.

```
foreach(string id in list) {
    myitemcollection.Remove(id); // This does not exist. How would I implement it?
}
```

Unfortunately, "Remove" takes a complete item, which I don't have, and "RemoveAt" takes an index, which I don't have either.

How can I achieve this? Nested loops will work, but is there a better way?

Comment: If only this was a `Dictionary<string, itemType>`.

Comment: `myitemcollection` type?

Comment: @Bharadwaj Collection<MyItem>, with MyItem being a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx):

```
foreach(string id in list) {
    //get item which matches the id
    var item = myitemcollection.Where(x => x.id == id);
    //remove that item
    myitemcollection.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: He said `Remove` doesn't exists.

Comment: I tried your answer and got it working when exchanging Where (returning a collection) for First (returning an item). @Bharadway Remove(string id) does not exist, but Remove(Item item) does.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx):

```
 var newCollection = myitemcollection.Where(x=> !list.Contains(x.ID));
```

Please note that:

1. This assumes that your Item collection has data member called `ID`.
2. This is not the best performance wise...

Answer (score 1):

If mycollection is also a list of ints, you could use

```
List<int> list = new List<int> {1,2,3};
List<int> myitemcollection = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6};
myitemcollection.RemoveAll(list.Contains);
```

If it is a custom class, lets say

```
public class myclass
{
    public int ID;
}
```

you could use

```
List<int> list = new List<int> {1,2,3};
List<myclass> myitemcollection = new List<myclass>
{
    new myclass { ID = 1},
    new myclass { ID = 2},
    new myclass { ID = 3},
    new myclass { ID = 4},
    new myclass { ID = 5},
    new myclass { ID = 6},
};

myitemcollection.RemoveAll(i => list.Contains(i.ID));
```

[List.RemoveAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the
>   specified predicate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question rightly, try the below code snip

```
foreach (string id in list)
{
    if (id == "") // check some condition to skip all other items in list
    {
        myitemcollection.Remove(id); // This does not exist. How would I implement it?
    }
}
```

If this is not good enough. Make your question more clear to get exact answer

Answer (score 0):

In terms of theory, you are dealing with a matter called closure.Within a loop (or for), you should make a copy of your list (or array or what you are iterating) in every way (that is mentioned differently by guys), mark those you want to remove and then deal with them out of the loop.